# Iterate over Numpy array for Tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, tensorflow

**Hello,**

I am entry level in Python.I have searched every doc on python and numpy but didn't find.I want to train my multivariable logistic regression model.*I have 100x2 numpy array* for train_x data and *100x1 numpy array* as train_y data.I just couldn't feed my placeholders.I think i can't able to iterate multidimensional matrix as placeholder wants.

Here is my raw code for better understand:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as numpy

learning_rate = 0.01
total_iterator = 1500
display_per = 100

data = numpy.loadtxt("ex2data1.txt",dtype=numpy.float32,delimiter=",");

training_X = numpy.asarray(data[:,[0,1]]) # 100 x 2
training_Y = numpy.asarray(data[:,[2]],dtype=numpy.int) # 100 x 1

m = data.shape[0] # thats my sample size = 100

x_i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2]) # N x 2
y_i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1]) # N x 1

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,1]))  # 2 x 1          
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))  # 1 x 1      

h = tf.matmul(W,x_i)+b

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(tf.multiply(y_i,tf.log(h)),tf.multiply(1-y_i,tf.log(1-h)))) / -m
### I just wanted to try simple cross function as i learned in lesson ###
### I didn't get such error at this scope ###

initializer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for k in range(total_iterator):    
        for (x,y) in  zip(training_X,training_Y):
            sess.run(initializer,feed_dict={x_i: x , y_i: y}) ### ?!??!? ###

            ### AT THIS SCOPE: i get error such as 'can't feed,
            ### placeholder:0'###

        if k % display_per==0:
            print("Iteration: ",k, "cost: ", sess.run(cost,feed_dict={x_i:training_X,y_i:training_Y}),"w: ",sess.run(W),\
                "b: ",sess.run(b))

    print("Optim. finished")
    print("Iteration: ", k, "cost: ", sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x_i: training_X, y_i: training_Y}), "w: ", sess.run(W), \
          "b: ", sess.run(b))
```

*Thanks for any answers*.I think i have pass two dimensional matrix slice from train_x to x_i.*Maybe i am wrong from start to end*.

Comment: Does it work if you add `x=x.reshape((1,2))` and `y=y.reshape((1,1))` right before the call to run?

Comment: Nope.
thanks for reply anyway

Comment: Can you post the whole exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `x`,`y` in the loop are 1-D, while the placeholder is 2-D. (Note you define the placeholder as `tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2])`, which defines a 2-D placeholder. This is done in order to do the optimization and calculations in batches).

The quickest solution would be to reshape `x` and `y`:

```
sess.run(initializer,feed_dict={x_i: np.reshape(x, [1,-1]),
                                y_i: np.reshape(y, [1, -1])})
```

Comment: it seems work,thanks a lot.Now i can't print cost function: print("Iteration: ",k, "cost: ", sess.run(cost,feed_dict={x_i:numpy.reshape(training_X, [1,-1]),y_i:numpy.reshape(training_Y, [1, -1])

Comment: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 200) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Comment: You need to reshape only the `x`,`y`. The `X_training` and `y_training` are already in the right shape (`100x2` and `100x1`) (The `None` in the `placeholder` definition makes it accept any size along the first axis)

Comment: i've tried but it returns [nan].even i've tested whole cost and model variables.x_i:training_X,y_i:training_Y simply doesn't send any value.Am i wrong?

Comment: That's a different problem. Either you data contains 'nan' to begin with, or the calculation returned `nan`. Usually, (at least for me), if it is the second case, lowering your `learning_rate` might help.

Comment: But you should just debug - check the value before iteration, check the values of the weights, check after each iteration, etc.

Comment: This is the new dimensions. The `-1` tells it to infer the dimension of this specific axis (the second) from the old dimensions (i.e., complete it to fit the data)

Comment: got it.thank you for reply.i accept answer.maybe i gotta open new ticket for that problem.